# calling function with unknown parameters

Tags: c++

I have to call function with few parameters. I don't know count of parameters but they are well known in compilling time. I need store it and cast to (void*)() but when reinvoke it, need to call it with parameters. I am assuming that parameters will be on the stack.

```
void f(int a, int b)
{
  ...
}

(void*)() c = (void*)()f; 

...
pop param2;
pop param1;
call c;
```

is it possible to do soemthing like that? I need it becouse I am looking for a way how to call function from my interpreter and wish to have something like compilling time function registration and than direct invoking it from my assembler. So I am assuming that parameters for function will be on my own stack. i could rewrite them to real stack and then invoke function with this parameters.

Or maybe there is other way to achieve this?

I'm using GCC.

this temporary solved my problem but it's very far from ideal:

```
auto& called = ctx.Functions[funcName];
shortWord param1;
shortWord param2;
switch(called.ParametersCount)
{
    case 0:
        called.Address();
        break;
    case 1:
        param1 = ctx.Locals.top();
        ctx.Locals.pop();
        (reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void*)>(called.Address))((void*)param1);
        break;
    case 2:
        param1 = ctx.Locals.top();
        ctx.Locals.pop();
        param2 = ctx.Locals.top();
        ctx.Locals.pop();
        (reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void*, void*)>(called.Address))((void*)param1, (void*)param2);
        break;
}

void ABC(shortWord sw)
{
    shortWord tmp = sw;
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Pick one, unless you want multiple answers.

Comment: C++ but I assumed that in C will be similar becouse I doesn't need complex types

Comment: It's impossible to do without assembly in C, but probably doable in C++11 with `std::bind`.

Comment: @Puchacz Maybe similar, but maybe not. C and C++ have different semantics regarding void pointers, for example.

Comment: Please pick one. I'll close this question as *too broad* otherwise.

Comment: FWIW it would be better to store the pointers simply as `void *` so that you don't actually call them with no arguments by mistake. `void *` is intended to be a "pointer to something, but we don't know what." Storing these function pointers in a `void (*)()` conveys the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

In C you'll have to manually do the calling convention but it isn't very hard, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl or consider using libffi to help you out. you can use libffi in C++ too, but it won't support all calling conventions (eg virtual calls, or a call to a non virtual class function)

In C++ you can use std::bind, however std::bind expects a complete function type, you won't be able to simply call a

```
typedef void (*n)();
```

You could create a macro to automatically both define the function and the std::function refence and store it somewhere, so you can later call it using std::bind, minus the define it would look something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

double d(double x, double y) { return x / y; }
std::function<double(double, double)> d_ref = d;


int main()
{
    double v1 = 10;
    double v2 = 20;

    printf("out1: %f\n", d(v1, v2));

    auto fn_d = std::bind(d_ref, v1, v2);

    printf("out2: %f\n", fn_d());

    printf("ok");
    getchar();
}
```